# How to trigger UIImageView animation in a UITableViewHeaderFooterView when pressing on a tableView section?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, xib, cgaffinetransform

I want to create an expandable/collapsable `tableView` cells behaviour with a custom header view from xib using `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

I have the following `CustomHeaderView` `xib` setup: UILabel, UIButton (to press on the header and trigger expandable/collapsable behaviour and chevron as `UIImageView` to represent a current section state:

[image]

Here is how a `CustomHeaderView` class looks. It has some outlets, method for rotating the `chevron` and simple `protocol` to tell my `ViewController` that certain `section` was tapped (button's tag == section)

```
import UIKit

 protocol HeaderViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func expandedSection(button: UIButton)
 }

class CustomHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

weak var delegate: HeaderViewDelegate?

@IBOutlet weak var lable: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var headerButton: UIButton!

func configure(title: String, section: Int) {
    lable.text = title
    headerButton.tag = section
}

func rotateImage(_ expanded: Bool) {
    if expanded {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.imageView.transform = .identity
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func tapHeader(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.expandedSection(button: sender)
}
}
```

Here is how my ViewController looks like:

```
import UIKit

struct ExpandedModel {
   var isExpanded: Bool
   let title: String
   let array: [String]
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

   let headerID = String(describing: CustomHeaderView.self)
   var arrayOfData = [ExpandedModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    arrayOfData = [
        ExpandedModel(isExpanded: true, title: "Words", array: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]),
        ExpandedModel(isExpanded: true, title: "Numbers", array: ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10"])
    ]
    tableViewConfig()
}

private func tableViewConfig() {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: headerID, bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: headerID)
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    arrayOfData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if !arrayOfData[section].isExpanded {
        return 0
    } else {
        return arrayOfData[section].array.count
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dataCell", for: indexPath) as! DataTableViewCell
    cell.label.text = arrayOfData[indexPath.section].array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerID) as! CustomHeaderView
    
    header.configure(title: arrayOfData[section].title, section: section)
    header.rotateImage(arrayOfData[section].isExpanded)
    header.delegate = self
    return header
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight
}
}

 extension TableViewController: HeaderViewDelegate {
    func expandedSection(button: UIButton) {
       let section = button.tag
       let indexPaths = (0..<(arrayOfData[section].array.count)).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: section)}
    
    arrayOfData[section].isExpanded.toggle()
    
    if !arrayOfData[section].isExpanded {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    } else {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
}
```

The main goal is ok - I can collapse and expand cells. But the problem is how to animate the `chevron` in `CustomHeaderView`?

If I'll use a reloading section method, then the `chevron` animation will be skipped:

```
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: section), with: .none)
```

[image]

If I will add a delay with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`, it will be animated in, but skipped when out:

```
        func rotateImage(_ expanded: Bool) {
        if expanded {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)
                }
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                self.imageView.transform = .identity
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

What is a most sufficient way to achieve a proper `chevron` animation?

**UPDATE**

According to DonMag's answer here is the working solution:

```
extension TableViewController: HeaderViewDelegate {
func expandedSection(button: UIButton) {
    let section = button.tag
    let indexPaths = (0..<(arrayOfData[section].array.count)).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: section)}
    
    arrayOfData[section].isExpanded.toggle()
    
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    
    if let header = tableView.headerView(forSection: section) as? CustomHeaderView {
                header.rotateImage(arrayOfData[section].isExpanded)
    }
    
    if !arrayOfData[section].isExpanded {
        tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    } else {
        tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    }
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
}
```

Comment: For info UICollectionView List and diffable datasource can handle this all for you. In the collectionViewLayout you have to use UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration.HeaderMode .firstItemInSection (it doesn't seem to be doable from UITableView and diffable data source as NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot is UICollectionView only)

Comment: Hi @glotcha. Thank you for the reply. I will take a look on suggested collectionView option. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your first block of code, do you get the animation you want if you change your `expandedSection(button: UIButton)` func to this:

```
extension TableViewController: HeaderViewDelegate {
    func expandedSection(button: UIButton) {
        let section = button.tag
        let indexPaths = (0..<(arrayOfData[section].array.count)).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: section)}
        
        arrayOfData[section].isExpanded.toggle()

        // get a reference to the section's header view    
        if let v = tableView.headerView(forSection: section) as? SomeCustomHeaderView {
            v.rotateImage(arrayOfData[section].isExpanded)
        }

        if !arrayOfData[section].isExpanded {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        } else {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, DonMag! Thank you, yes, it was helpful. I just refactor the method a little bit, posted in question as update. Thank you!